# How to display Decimal value in <telerik:radnumerictextbox> control?

Tags: asp.net, html, vb.net, telerik

I am using  telerik:radnumerictextbox control for giving decimal input, 
I need to give input in decimal like 10, but radnumerictextbox displays value by default 10.00, how to set the property to get decimal value.

This is the code i am using in client side.

```
<telerik:radnumerictextbox 
        ID="txtDirectTime" 
        ShowSpinButtons="True" 
        InterceptArrowKeys="True" 
        Step="5" MinValue="0" runat="server">
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
<telerik:RadNumericTextBox runat="server"
                           ID="YourTextBox"
                           NumberFormat-DecimalDigits="2" />
```

For more on `RadNumericTextBox` visit [here](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/input-numerictextbox-formatting-numeric-values.html).

Comment: thanks, you are saying DecimalDigits="2", but i don't want to set size, bcoz it restrict only 2 digits, 0-1000 is the value range for me.

Comment: I guess @Lakshmitha need `NumberFormat-DecimalDigits="0"`

Comment: when its exceeds 3 digits its showing value by ',' separator for example 1,000. how to remove ',' ?

Answer (score 2):

`NumberFormat-GroupSeparator=""` works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

In answer to your supplemental question, "how to remove ',' [thousands separator]?".

Use the NumberFormat GroupSeparator property, either as an attribute on the control tag:

```
<telerik:RadNumericTextBox ID="RadNumericTextBox1" Runat="server"
    NumberFormat-GroupSeparator="" />
```

or as a child element:

```
<telerik:RadNumericTextBox ID="RadNumericTextBox1" Runat="server">
    <NumberFormat GroupSeparator="" />
</telerik:RadNumericTextBox>
```

Reference: [RadNumericTextBox Formatting Numeric Values (Telerik)](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/input-numerictextbox-formatting-numeric-values.html)